# PostgreSQL and Crosstab(): ERROR: return and sql tuple descriptions are incompatible

Tags: sql, postgresql, crosstab

I am running the following basic `SQL` query:

```
SELECT
  a.project_name,
  CASE
    WHEN to_char(date_trunc('month', u.billing_period_start), 'MM-YYYY') = '07-2016' THEN 'July_2016'
    WHEN to_char(date_trunc('month', u.billing_period_start), 'MM-YYYY') = '08-2016' THEN 'August_2016'
    WHEN to_char(date_trunc('month', u.billing_period_start), 'MM-YYYY') = '09-2016' THEN 'September_2016'
  END AS billing_month,
  u.unique_visitor_count AS visitors
FROM table_1 u,
     (SELECT
       a.account_id AS project_id,
       a.project_name
     FROM table_2 a) a
WHERE u.project_id = a.project_id
AND date_trunc('month', u.billing_period_start) BETWEEN '2016-07-01' AND '2016-09-01'
ORDER BY 1, 2;
```

This query gets me the following result set:

`project_name | month_name      | visitors`

`-------------|----------------|---------`

`name_1       | August_2016    | 0`

`name_1       | July_2016      | 0`

`name_1       | September_2016 | 0`

`name_2       | August_2016    | 0`

`name_2       | July_2016      | 0`

`name_2       | September_2016 | 0`

`name_3       | August_2016    | 39`

`name_3       | July_2016      | 68`

`name_3       | September_2016 | 25`

`name_4       | August_2016    | 536914`

`name_4       | July_2016      | 16142`

`name_4       | September_2016 | 487117`

I am trying to use the following `crosstab()` query:

```
SELECT * FROM crosstab
('SELECT 
    a.project_name,
    case when to_char(date_trunc(''month'', u.billing_period_start),''MM-YYYY'')=''07-2016'' then ''July_2016''
         when to_char(date_trunc(''month'', u.billing_period_start),''MM-YYYY'')=''08-2016'' then ''August_2016''
         when to_char(date_trunc(''month'', u.billing_period_start),''MM-YYYY'')=''09-2016'' then ''September_2016'' end as billing_month,
    u.unique_visitor_count as visitors
FROM table_1 u,
     (select a.account_id as project_id, a.project_name
      from table_2 a) a
where u.project_id = a.project_id
and date_trunc(''month'', u.billing_period_start) between ''2016-07-01'' and ''2016-09-01''
order by 1,2')
AS (project_name TEXT, July_2016 INTEGER, August_2016 INTEGER, September_2016 INTEGER);
```

I want to turn the first result set above into the following:

`project_name | July_2016 | August_2016 | September_2016`

`------------|-----------|-------------|---------------`

`name_1      | 0         | 0           | 0`

`name_2      | 0         | 0           | 0`

`name_3      | 68        | 39          | 25`

`name_4      | 16142     | 536914      | 487117`

However I am receiving the error:

> ERROR: return and sql tuple descriptions are incompatible

I will never have any null or missing results for `visitors`. I have read previous posts about the second parameter for `crosstab()` and I don't believe I need it here.  I have tried changing the `INTEGER` columns in my `crosstab()` to `NUMERIC`, but I still receive the same error.

What am I doing wrong? Could someone provide a modified, working `crosstab()` query to show me a fix?

Answer (score 0):

I would just use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT a.project_name,
       SUM(case when date_trunc('month', u.billing_period_start) = '2016-07-01'
                then u.unique_visitor_count else 0
           end) as uv_201607,
       SUM(case when date_trunc('month', u.billing_period_start) = '2016-08-01' 
                then u.unique_visitor_count else 0
           end) as uv_201608,
       SUM(case when date_trunc('month', u.billing_period_start) = '2016-09-01' 
                then u.unique_visitor_count else 0
           end) as uv_201609
FROM table_1 u JOIN
     table_2 a
     ON u.project_id = a.project_id
WHERE  date_trunc('month', u.billing_period_start) BETWEEN '2016-07-01' AND '2016-09-01'
GROUP BY a.project_name
ORDER BY a.project_name;
```

Notes:

- There is no need to use `to_char()` on `date_trunc()`.
- Use standard formats for dates -- YYYY-MM-DD.
- The subquery in the `FROM` clause is unnecessary.
- *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  Always use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: Thanks @gordon-linoff.  Agreed that my date formatting was a little sloppy; I had pursued that in some failed attempts to get `crosstab()` to behave. My `FROM` subquery is intentionally obfuscated to protect some proprietary information - it's not material to my core issue.  I want to stick with `crosstab()` because I have a lot more date columns to incorporate - these three are a representative example. I understand from other posts I may have to abandon this approach because I have an unknown number of future date columns to build, but now I'm just curious how to get this example to work.